# Detect when a file descriptor is from /proc

Tags: c++, c, linux, linux-kernel

Files from the /proc directory cannot be read in the normal way. In particular, fstat will tell you that the file is zero size even when there is content.

This plays havoc with some of my file reading code that first asks for the file size before reading. Essentially you have to read files from /proc more like you would read a pipe or stdin - read until you get the EOF.

But, how can I detect if a file descriptor, or FILE* is from /proc?

Looking at the content of stat after doing an fstat I don't see any clear way of detecting this. Nothing in st_mode, or ownership or permissions can definitively tell me its from /proc.

The device id looks promising - on the systems I've tried it comes back as 3, where regular disks have a higher number ( like 801). But is it always guaranteed to be 3? I can't find an official supported way.

Looking for an answer in c/c++

Comment: Change your logic so your code can work with a pipe.  Then stop caring.

Comment: Why does your code need to know the file size?

Comment: This is a clear XY issue. You're reading from FDs wrongly. You don't need the filesize. A filesize doesn't exist with a stream or pipe. Remove that constraint and you're done.

Comment: This is for a class the reads the contents of a file to a single buffer. It is way easier and nicer to preallocate the whole buffer up front, than to keep resizing it.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista So an easy workaround would be: if the file size is zero then *assume* that the file is a special file that might have contents, and drop into that code. If it truly is empty then you will wind up with an empty buffer anyway. Otherwise (if the file size is nonzero) take the optimized path where you preallocate the buffer.

Comment: @cdhowie: could work. But awkward. Code has options for reading partial files, read from end of file, there are error checks for failure to read expected file size etc. Regardless - it would be good to know how to detect this condition.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista The simplest way I can think of would be if the file size is zero, try to peek one byte. If that succeeds, then you are probably reading such a special file.

Comment: `/proc` files aren't the only files that behave this way - eg. there's also `/sys` files.  It's also possible for a regular file to change size between when you called `fstat()` and when you read it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok answer found.

```
#include <sys/statfs.h>
#include <linux/magic.h>

struct statfs fs;
fstatfs( fileno( file ), &fs );
bool isProc = ( fs.f_type == PROC_SUPER_MAGIC ) ? true : false;
```